# javafx barchart. set minimum width or height of each bar

Tags: javafx-2, bar-chart

I've created horizontal bar chart with category axis (Y axis). After adding more and more categories to Y axis, height of each horizontal bar is shrinked to zero size.
[image: shrinked bars]
Here we can see bars with height of 2px, but I want to have at least 6px.

How to restrict height of each bar on the chart?
And how to force chart to request more space if bars for all categories are not fitted in plot area?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time you add a new category, increase the minHeight property of the chart.

Comment: I already use this technique. Is there any more convenient and automated way?

Comment: No, there is no more convenient, automated way.